# A verb for getting in pose of stubborn confrontation

Tags: verbs, expressions

What verb could I use when a person is getting in the pose of stubborn confrontation? Kind of aggressive, but restrained, the same way when a bull is frozen, waiting for an attack to start?

For a man, it would be a pose with straightened shoulders and jaw moved forward, with a slightly lowered head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a "defensive posture/stance" (we wouldn't commonly use "pose" here), so a suitable verb might be "adopting", e.g. "He adopted a defensive posture as the wild raccoon approached him".

[UCD Digital Library example](https://doi.org/10.7925/drs1.ucdlib_30728)

Comment: Thanks! I had a hope, there would be one verb or at least an idiom for "adopted a defensive/aggressive posture"

Comment: Colloquially you might use something like "squared up" or "dug in", but I think that depends a lot on context.

Comment: Thanks a lot, "square up to sb/sth" hit it!

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, there isn't one word.

"Aggressive posture" is the best I can come up with.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to the ELL. You could improve your answer by providing some reliable resources for the information you are giving.

Comment: What do you think about "square up to sb/sth"?